# phasset subtypes rawValue meaning swift

Tags: swift, phasset

I'm trying to detect the subtypes of a PHAsset.

```
asset.subtypes.rawvalue -> UInt
```

I found the meaning of subtypes .video (rawValue: 0) and photoLive (rawValue: 8) but I have livePhoto with HDR option and the subtypes rawavlue is 10 and I don't find the meaning of the value.
Someone has all rawValue meaning of PHAsset subtypes? 
Thanks

Comment: "Media subtypes are bit mask values, so you can combine them using bitwise operators to test for multiple subtypes." (source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetmediasubtype?language=objc) . So rawValue = 10 is 2+8, so it's both whatever is the subtype at value = 2 AND photoLive (which value is 8).

Comment: @Larme Thanks your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation of `PHAssetMediaSubtype`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetmediasubtype?language=objc):

> Media subtypes are bit mask values, so you can combine them using
>   bitwise operators to test for multiple subtypes.

The definition helps to:

```
typedef enum PHAssetMediaSubtype : NSUInteger {
    PHAssetMediaSubtypeNone = 0,
    PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoPanorama = (1UL << 0),
    PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoHDR = (1UL << 1),
    PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoScreenshot = (1UL << 2),
    PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoLive = (1UL << 3),
    PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoDepthEffect = (1UL << 4),
    PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoStreamed = (1UL << 16),
    PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate = (1UL << 17),
    PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoTimelapse = (1UL << 18)
} PHAssetMediaSubtype;
```

So, if subtype is 10, then 10 being 8+2 (which the unique possible "sub-values"), it's whatever is the value 8 (`.photoLive`) and whatever is the value 2  (.HDR).

Comment: Thanks Larme that was what I looked for!